# ReactJS: making props available in static function of composed component

Tags: reactjs, redux, react-router, react-redux

I have a higher order component, that provides the complete website layout, including a sidebar. This sidebar contains some static elements (e.g. a logo, the home button, imprint and disclaimer) and some dynamic content, provided by the composed component.

```
const HtmlSkeleton = (ComposedComponent) => {
    class Wrapper extends Component {
        [...]
        render() {
            return (
                <div>
                    <Sidebar content={ComposedComponent.getSidebarContent()} />
                    <Header />
                    <Content>
                        <ComposedComponent {...this.props} />
                    </Content>
                    </Footer />
                </div>
            )
        }
    }

    return connect(...)(Wrapper)
}
```

Then I have some views/containers, that will be composed by that HOC:

```
class View extends Component {
     static getSidebarContent = () => {
         // how to access someFunction?!?

         return [...some stuff depending on props. How do I have access?]
     }
     constructor(props) {
          [....]
     }
     [...]
     someFunction = () => { [....] }
     render() {
        this.someFunction()
        [...]
    }
}
export default connect(....)(HtmlSkeleton(View))
```

(connect is from react-redux, but not that important in that case)

Or is there any other possibility to keep the layout in some kind of component, that I don´t see? Where do you keep the basic HTML?
I´m using react-router, react-redux and redux-saga.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can pass the props directly to your `getSidebarContent`:

```
<Sidebar content={ComposedComponent.getSidebarContent(this.props)} />
```

And retrieve them in your function:

```
class View extends Component {
     static getSidebarContent = (props) => {
         return ...
     }
     [...]
}
```

Comment: I already did that, and it works. I was wondering, if this is the way to go. Seems kind of strange to me. :-)

Comment: You loose all other context of your composed component within the static function. Let´s say there is a function within the component, that your static function and other component function need access to - you won´t have access to that function within your static function, because you do not have access to "this". So you need to source this function out an pass the props to it... I´ll update the topic entry to make clearer, what I mean.

Comment: I am not sure how you end up in that situation. If you want to access the state of your class, then a static function is not what you want. You should make Sidebar a component on its own and have its content driven entirely from your redux state (through props)

Comment: Sidebar is a separate component already. The additional content of Sidebar is based on the url and query and therefore on different parts of the state. So the idea was, that the view containers define this content. Unfortunately the Sidebar and some other parts of the layout (footer, content, ...) share some logic, e.g. Footer and Sidebar share the logic to get a URL for pagination ("someFunction" in the first post).

Comment: then you could put some function in a separate utils file for example and have SideBar, content and Footer as 3 different classes

Comment: Ok, sounds reasonable. :-) That´s the way I´ll go then. Thanks a lot.